# Resizing Tkinter Canvas rectangles

Tags: tkinter, canvas, resize

Have been trying to resize a matrix like canvas rectangles. Have been trying to resize a particular colum in the matrix, it does but it didn't update on the screen as obvious i want it.

Resizing the width of the a specific colum precisely.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
container = Canvas(root, width =1140,height=750)
for r in range(50):
    for c in range(12):
        x1 = c*145
        y1 = r*34
        x2 = x1 + 145
        y2 = y1 + 34
       
        container.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,width=1,fill='white',outline='grey60')
container.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

How can I resize a specific column in this matrix.

Comment: You'll need to adjust the x2 coordinate on all the rectangles in the column and the x1 and x2 coordinates of all the rectangles to the column's right.  It'll be best to store the rectangle objects in a list of lists ( rows x columns ) as they are created.

Comment: *"Have been trying to resize a particular colum in the matrix, it does but it didn't update on the screen as obvious i want it."*  Post what you have tried then.

Comment: @Tls Chris have tried updating the column x2 width but it seems nothing happened but it does. I think the problem is that the column beside it is obscuring the remaining part. Pls how can I achieve the expansion without obscurity.

Comment: You need to update the `x_` coords for every rectangle to the right of the column too.  If column 3 is wider columns 4 and more all need to start at a greater `x1` and finish at a greater `x2`.

Comment: @Tls Chris OK. I will try that. Using for loop, will it work.?

Comment: Try it and edit your question with the code if it doesn't work.  If it does work post the answer to your own question for others to use in future.